# How to calculate $\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2}\frac{dxdydz}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}$, where $a^2+b^2+c^2>R^2$?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Let$a^2+b^2+c^2>R^2$, calculate $\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2}\frac{dxdydz}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}$.

Let $(x,y,z)=(a+r\sin\phi\cos \theta,b+r\sin\phi\sin \theta,z=c+r\cos\phi)$, but I don’t know how to transform the integration region. Is there any good idea?

Comment: you're integrating a harmonic function over a ball, so the integral is the value of the function at the center of the ball, times the volume of the ball

Comment: It's amazing, is there a more elementary way to calculate it directly?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a transformation to a coordinate system centered at the point $(a,b,c)$ but rotated such that the origin lies on the $z$ axis relative to the point $(a,b,c)$. This gives us the integral

$$I = \iiint\limits_{x^2+y^2+\left(z-\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\right)^2\leq R^2}\frac{dV}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

Then convert to spherical coordinates and do the angular integral first.

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}-R}^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}+R}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2+a^2+b^2+c^2-R^2}{2r\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)}r\sin\theta\:d\theta\:dr\:d\theta$$

$$= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\int_{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}-R}^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}+R}2r\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}-(r^2+a^2+b^2+c^2-R^2)\:dr$$

$$= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\left(2R(a^2+b^2+c^2+R^2)-2R(a^2+b^2+c^2)-\frac{2}{3}R^3\right)$$

$$\implies \boxed{I = \frac{4\pi R^3}{3\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}}$$

which is exactly the volume of the sphere times the value of the original integrand at the origin.

Comment: How do you determine the range of values for $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: @Ychen The equation of the sphere tells us $$x^2+y^2+z^2=2z\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}-(a^2+b^2+c^2-R^2)$$ $$\implies r^2 = 2r\cos\theta\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}-(a^2+b^2+c^2-R^2)$$ when converting to polar coordinates. From here it is a simple matter of solving for cosine. The $r$ bounds are found by simply considering the minimum and maximum reach of the $r$ variable, which by the cleverly chosen symmetry occurs directly on the $z$ axis.